# check php array for key/value duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

My array is something like this:

```
   $sth = array(
        array("group" => "1", "name" => "John", "whatever" => "a"),
        array("group" => "1", "name" => "John", "whatever" => "b"), // this is the duplicate I want to remove
        array("group" => "1", "name" => "Henry", "whatever" => "c"),
        array("group" => "2", "name" => "John", "whatever" => "d"),
        array("group" => "2", "name" => "Peter", "whatever" => "e")
    )
```

And I want to remove the duplicate `1/John` entry, but not the `2/John` since it's not a duplicate. I only want to check those two values, not the "whatever" value, since that will always be different. I know I could use `in_array` to search for just `"John"`, or `array_search` to check the keys, but the keys don't always correlate to the name, so I need to only remove duplicates where the `key/value` are the exact same. I'm thinking something like:

```
$cleaned_sth = array();
foreach($sth as $s) {
    $group = $s[0];
    $name = $s[1];
    if( in_array($group => $name, $cleaned_sth ) continue;
    else $cleaned_sth[] = array("group" => $group, "name" => $name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pseudocode (since I don't program in PHP for a long time now).

```
define an empty map
foreach(entry in array) map[entry["group"] + entry["name"]] = entry
map.values
```